# Python packet sniffer problems running

Tags: python, networking, packet-sniffers

I created a python code that is meant to be a basic packet sniffer.  The code compiles however when it runs it gives no errors but there is no output either.   My main question is what went wrong with the code.  Open to suggestions.  I have used IDLE and coderunner on OS X to attempt to get a running program.

Here is what I have so far thanks.

```
import socket
import struct
import textwrap

TAB_1 = '\t - '
TAB_2 = '\t\t - '
TAB_3 = '\t\t\t - '
TAB_4 = '\t\t\t\t - '

DATA_TAB_1 = '\t   '
DATA_TAB_2 = '\t\t   '
DATA_TAB_3 = '\t\t\t   '
DATA_TAB_4 = '\t\t\t\t   '


def main():
    pcap = Pcap('capture.pcap')
    conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.ntohs(3))

    while True:
        raw_data, addr = conn.recvfrom(65535)
        pcap.write(raw_data)
        eth = Ethernet(raw_data)

        print('\nEthernet Frame:')
        print(TAB_1 + 'Destination: {}, Source: {}, Protocol: {}'.format(eth.dest_mac, eth.src_mac, eth.proto))

        # IPv4
        if eth.proto == 8:
            ipv4 = IPv4(eth.data)
            print(TAB_1 + 'IPv4 Packet:')
            print(TAB_2 + 'Version: {}, Header Length: {}, TTL: {},'.format(ipv4.version, ipv4.header_length, ipv4.ttl))
            print(TAB_2 + 'Protocol: {}, Source: {}, Target: {}'.format(ipv4.proto, ipv4.src, ipv4.target))

            # ICMP
            if ipv4.proto == 1:
                icmp = ICMP(ipv4.data)
                print(TAB_1 + 'ICMP Packet:')
                print(TAB_2 + 'Type: {}, Code: {}, Checksum: {},'.format(icmp.type, icmp.code, icmp.checksum))
                print(TAB_2 + 'ICMP Data:')
                print(format_multi_line(DATA_TAB_3, icmp.data))

            # TCP
            elif ipv4.proto == 6:
                tcp = TCP(ipv4.data)
                print(TAB_1 + 'TCP Segment:')
                print(TAB_2 + 'Source Port: {}, Destination Port: {}'.format(tcp.src_port, tcp.dest_port))
                print(TAB_2 + 'Sequence: {}, Acknowledgment: {}'.format(tcp.sequence, tcp.acknowledgment))
                print(TAB_2 + 'Flags:')
                print(TAB_3 + 'URG: {}, ACK: {}, PSH: {}'.format(tcp.flag_urg, tcp.flag_ack, tcp.flag_psh))
                print(TAB_3 + 'RST: {}, SYN: {}, FIN:{}'.format(tcp.flag_rst, tcp.flag_syn, tcp.flag_fin))

                if len(tcp.data) > 0:

                    # HTTP
                    if tcp.src_port == 80 or tcp.dest_port == 80:
                        print(TAB_2 + 'HTTP Data:')
                        try:
                            http = HTTP(tcp.data)
                            http_info = str(http.data).split('\n')
                            for line in http_info:
                                print(DATA_TAB_3 + str(line))
                        except:
                            print(format_multi_line(DATA_TAB_3, tcp.data))
                    else:
                        print(TAB_2 + 'TCP Data:')
                        print(format_multi_line(DATA_TAB_3, tcp.data))

            # UDP
            elif ipv4.proto == 17:
                udp = UDP(ipv4.data)
                print(TAB_1 + 'UDP Segment:')
                print(TAB_2 + 'Source Port: {}, Destination Port: {}, Length: {}'.format(udp.src_port, udp.dest_port, udp.size))

            # Other IPv4
            else:
                print(TAB_1 + 'Other IPv4 Data:')
                print(format_multi_line(DATA_TAB_2, ipv4.data))

        else:
            print('Ethernet Data:')
            print(format_multi_line(DATA_TAB_1, eth.data))

# Returns MAC as string from bytes (ie AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF)
def get_mac_addr(mac_raw):
    byte_str = map('{:02x}'.format, mac_raw)
    mac_addr = ':'.join(byte_str).upper()
    return mac_addr

def ipv4_packet(self, raw_data):
        version_header_length = raw_data[0]
        self.version = version_header_length >> 4
        self.header_length = (version_header_length & 15) * 4
        self.ttl, self.proto, src, target = struct.unpack('! 8x B B 2x 4s 4s', raw_data[:20])
        self.src = self.ipv4(src)
        self.target = self.ipv4(target)
        self.data = raw_data[self.header_length:]

# Returns properly formatted IPv4 address
def ipv4(self, addr):
    return '.'.join(map(str, addr))

def icmp_packet(self, raw_data):
        self.type, self.code, self.checksum = struct.unpack('! B B H', raw_data[:4])
        self.data = raw_data[4:]

def tcp_segment(self, raw_data):
        (self.src_port, self.dest_port, self.sequence, self.acknowledgment, offset_reserved_flags) = struct.unpack(
            '! H H L L H', raw_data[:14])
        offset = (offset_reserved_flags >> 12) * 4
        self.flag_urg = (offset_reserved_flags & 32) >> 5
        self.flag_ack = (offset_reserved_flags & 16) >> 4
        self.flag_psh = (offset_reserved_flags & 8) >> 3
        self.flag_rst = (offset_reserved_flags & 4) >> 2
        self.flag_syn = (offset_reserved_flags & 2) >> 1
        self.flag_fin = offset_reserved_flags & 1
        self.data = raw_data[offset:]

def udp_segment(self, raw_data):
        self.src_port, self.dest_port, self.size = struct.unpack('! H H 2x H', raw_data[:8])
        self.data = raw_data[8:]        

# Formats multi-line data
def format_multi_line(prefix, string, size=80):
    size -= len(prefix)
    if isinstance(string, bytes):
        string = ''.join(r'\x{:02x}'.format(byte) for byte in string)
        if size % 2:
            size -= 1
    return '\n'.join([prefix + line for line in textwrap.wrap(string, size)])
```

## curiosity... thenewboston

Comment: Your code had several problems. The most severe: you have function, but you never run them;  `__init__` outside of a class does not make sense; you are overwriting several functions by defining a new one with the same name.

Comment: Sorry about that Klaus D. I posted the wrong copy, just edited it should be a little better now.

Comment: You still don't call any function and you are having methods without a class.

Answer (score 0):

> I have used IDLE and coderunner on OS X to attempt to get a running program.

...

> `conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.ntohs(3))`

That's not going to work on OS X; OS X doesn't have `AF_PACKET` as an address family.  I'm surprised your program didn't fail with an exception.

If you're going to capture packet traffic, you should use pcap; you're already using it to write the capture file, you should use it to capture packets.  It will use the OS's mechanism (BPF, on OS X, *BSD, AIX, and Solaris 11; `AF_PACKET` sockets on Linux; etc.) to capture packets.